# Order Springdoc operation parameters alphabetically

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin

Migrating from springfox - springdoc

springfox generated an openApi definition that ordered all the parameters in alphabetical order, I've migrated to springdoc, but have been unable to find a way to keep the springfox ordering(alpha) of the parameters, e.g.

**Controller:**

```
getPerson(name, address, mobile)
```

**springfox generated openApi definition:**

```
getPersonService(address, mobile, name)
```

**springdoc generated openApi definition:**

```
getPersonService(name, address, mobile)
```

There are properties to order other aspects of the generated definition with:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.operationsSorter=method
springdoc.swagger-ui.tagsSorter=alpha
springdoc.writer-with-order-by-keys: true
```

I have been unable to find a property to order the operation parameters, is there a setting to accomplish this? or can it be achieved cleanly with:
`OpenApiCustomiser` or `OperationCustomizer`

Comment: There's nothing in-build to support the same. As you said, you can try overriding the `OperationCustomizer` method and try.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the `OperationCustomizer` (Kotlin Syntax):

```
@Bean
fun parameterOrderCustomizer(): OperationCustomizer {
    return OperationCustomizer { operation, _ ->
        operation.apply {
            parameters = parameters?.sortedBy { it.name }
        }
    }
}
```

and in case youre using grouped apis, dont forget to also add them to the groups via `.addOperationCustomizer(parameterOrderCustomizer())`

Answer (score 0):

Update your application.property file with:

```
springdoc.writer-with-order-by-keys=true
```

or in application.yaml file

```
springdoc
 writer-with-order-by-keys: true
```

Paths, schemas and properties is sorted ascending alphabetically perfectly fine